# Can't change brightness on a Acer Aspire v5-171

Tags: brightness

i found a solution on a site but i don't manage to do it

You need to enter `acpi_backlight=vendor` in `/etc/default/grub` boot options for the brightness keys to work.

Brightness can be adjusted with command `echo (level) > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` as super user (`su`, not `sudo`).

Maximum brightness can be found with `cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness`.

I Found it on this site: http://www.linlap.com/acer_aspire_v5-171

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>This is just how you add the line to the grub configuration:</sub>

Open `/etc/default/grub` by running this in terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Add the line in inside the quotes, it may look something like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor pcie_aspm=force"
```

Save with +<kbd>O</kbd>, and exit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

Then update the configuration with:

```
sudo update-grub
```

or with

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Then reboot.

<sub>For editing other stuff in `/etc/default/grub`, there is a manual page [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Simple-configuration)</sub>